# Is the example of wls in statsmodels wrong?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

The completed code of wls's example can be found here: [Weighted Least Squares](http://www.statsmodels.org/0.6.1/examples/notebooks/generated/wls.html), I'll copy it for convenience.

```
In [1]: from __future__ import print_function
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: from scipy import stats
   ...: import statsmodels.api as sm
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std
   ...: from statsmodels.iolib.table import (SimpleTable, default_txt_fmt)
   ...: np.random.seed(1024)
   ...: 

In [2]: nsample = 50
   ...: x = np.linspace(0, 20, nsample)
   ...: X = np.column_stack((x, (x - 5)**2))
   ...: X = sm.add_constant(X)
   ...: beta = [5., 0.5, -0.01]
   ...: sig = 0.5
   ...: w = np.ones(nsample)
   ...: w[nsample * 6 // 10:] = 3
   ...: y_true = np.dot(X, beta)
   ...: e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)
   ...: y = y_true + sig * w * e
   ...: X = X[:,[0,1]]
   ...: 

In [3]: 
   ...: mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X, weights=1./w)
   ...: res_wls = mod_wls.fit()
   ...: print(res_wls.summary())
   ...:
```

What has confused me is this line in codes:

```
mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X, weights=1./w)
```

According to [the docs of WLS](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html):

> The weights are presumed to be (proportional to) the inverse of the
>   variance of the observations. That is, if the variables are to be
>   transformed by 1/sqrt(W) you must supply weights = 1/W.

So, should not the wls model be build by:

```
mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X, weights=1./w ** 2)
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: This looks like a mistake in the entire notebook. WLS "whitens" using sqrt: `X * np.sqrt(weights)`

Comment: @user333700 Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, `w` in the example is specified in terms of standard deviation, while WLS `weights` need to be in terms of the variance, i.e. quadratic as in your last code line. (The error is not obvious in the results because the `params` are estimated consistently even if the weights are wrong, but the standard errors are wrong.)

Comment: I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3898